# Check if event exists by using event ID

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to see if a Google Calendar event exists by using the ID to search for it.

I have a list of Google Calendar Event ID's and I want to `foreach` loop through the ID's and I want to check if the ID's exist in the Google Calendar account.

Here's the code:

```
$eventId = '1234567890';
$event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);
var_dump($event);
```

The event obviously does not exist so it should say `NULL` or something like that.

But instead, it is showing Error 500 from Google's API in my error log. It says:

> "message": "Not Found"

How can i make it show just `NULL`?

Comment: Why not check if the event returns contains a message of "Not Found"?

Comment: @dustytrash How can i check for that?

Comment: added an answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could check if the api returned a object with a message of "Not Found".

E.G:

```
function getResultFromApi($eventId)
{
    $event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);

    // If we get a "Not Found", set to null
    if(isset($event.message) && $event.message == "Not Found")
    {
        $event = NULL;
    }
    return $event;
}

$myEventId = '1234567890';

getResultFromApi($myEventId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this:

```
try {
    $event = $service->events->get('primary', $eventId);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    // Error
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```